# Change URL of Chrome Extension upon refresh / ctrl-r

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code running in my Chrome Extension and the background page of the Chrome Extension:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  window.location.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('dist/index.html'); // change url
  confirm('are you sure you want to refresh?');
};
```

neither of these hooks seem to get hit. Does anyone know if there is a way to change the URL when refresh happens? I'd like to reload a different URL than the current one in the omnibox.

Comment: I think your popup is being ignored: ["Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`tabs API`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

You can listen change of the url with [`tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) and then in callback and then use [`tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) to change URL.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions are tremendously powerful.

I would suggest using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event to capture when the page has changed and then use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject a `window.location.replace` call.

Something like this, but you'll need to handle edge cases.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (p.tab && p.tab.id === tabId && tab.status !== p.lastStatus) {//correct tab and not a duplicate status
        if (tab.status === 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(p.tab.id, { code: "window.location.replace('');", runAt: 'document_start' }, function () {
                console.log('script injected');
            });
        }
    }
});
```